# How to place different marker for each marker added to map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to know if it is possible when placing a marker on the map, to then select from a list which marker to place. So for example, when the user wants to place a marker at a point of interest, like lets say a castle,  then the user can select from various marker icons from a list and select the marker (castle icon) and place it on the map.  Is this possible? and if so is there an example to follow or can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

Something like this:

[image: This guy has got it to display various markers on the map, (in this case animals)]

Answer (score 1):

MarkerOptions can be added at any particular latitude and longitude. Yon can set its title, alpha value, marker icon color etc. Snippet content will be shown in marker info window when marker is clicked. We need to ensure to moveCamera to your coordinates with required zoom level (9 in below example). You can check [map tutorial](http://androidsrc.net/google-maps-android-api-v2-tutorial/).

GoogleMap object will be available from onMapReady() callback.

```
LatLng NYC = new LatLng(40.714, -74.00);
googleMap.addMarker(
      new MarkerOptions().position(NYC).alpha(0.8f).title("NYC")
            .snippet("AndroidSRC Map Demo")).setIcon(
      BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(NYC, 9));
```

Comment: Thanks,  but what i would like is when the user taps the map to place a marker then a list view should appear with different styles of marker i.e. one marker that looks like a castle, the other one like a church etc.  Then when selected to place that marker on the map.  So basically the user can choose which marker he or she want to display

Comment: With new MarkerOptions().setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.castle)) etc, you can set custom icon as well. So you can create global variable for GoogleMap and intialize it in onMapReady() callback. So when user selects custom icon, check if map object is not null and set selceted icon marker.

Answer (score 0):

See method addMarker and class MarkerOptions.

```
Marker mark = map.addMarker(
    new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latlng)
        .title(title)
        .icon(icon)
);
```

Using MarkerOptions you can define custom icon when adding your marker.

In my example, *latlng* is LatLng object with coordinates, *title* is a String containting the title and *icon* is BitmapDescriptor for a custom marker icon.

Also, it seems that Marker has its own method *setIcon(BitmapDescriptor icon)* which can be used after the marker is added to map I guess.

Comment: Thanks,  i have edited my question with a screen shot of what I am basically looking for (instead of animals i want to use buildings :-) )